# Active Directory authentication with JWT in Python FastAPI

Tags: python, jwt, active-directory, fastapi

I am trying to implement a combination of Active Directory authentication with JWT in Python FastAPI.

Is this possible to use Active Directory authentication for acquiring a JWT token and then use that JWT for accessing a secured endpoint. Below is the code I have tried.

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, Depends, HTTPException
from fastapi.security import OAuth2PasswordBearer
from passlib.context import CryptContext
import jwt
from jwt.exceptions import ExpiredSignatureError, InvalidSignatureError
import datetime

app = FastAPI()

SECRET_KEY = "C4460C71-7A98-4356-A6DC-CC9F3FBBB63E"
pwd_context = CryptContext(schemes=["bcrypt"], deprecated="auto")

oauth2_scheme = OAuth2PasswordBearer(tokenUrl="/login")


def create_access_token(data: dict, expires_delta: datetime.timedelta):
    print("DEBUG: [create_access_token()]:", data)
    to_encode = data.copy()
    expires = datetime.datetime.utcnow() + expires_delta
    to_encode.update({"exp": expires})
    encoded_jwt = jwt.encode(to_encode, data["access_token"], algorithm="HS256")
    return encoded_jwt


def decode_token(token: str):
    decoded_token = jwt.decode(token, SECRET_KEY, algorithms=["HS256"])
    return decoded_token


async def get_current_user(token: str = Depends(oauth2_scheme)):
    try:
        decoded_token = decode_token(token)
        username = decoded_token.get("sub")
        print("DEBUG: [get_current_user()]:", username)
        if not username:
            raise HTTPException(status_code=401, detail="Invalid authentication token")
    except (ExpiredSignatureError):
        raise HTTPException(status_code=440, detail="Token has explired")
    except (InvalidSignatureError):
        raise HTTPException(status_code=498, detail="Invalid token")
    return {"username": username}


@app.post("/login/{access_token}")
async def login(access_token: str):
    # Authenticate the user against your AD
    # Generate a JWT token if authentication is successful
    access_token_expires = datetime.timedelta(minutes=5)
    expires = datetime.datetime.utcnow() + access_token_expires
    access_token = create_access_token(
        data={"sub": "user_id", "access_token": access_token}, expires_delta=access_token_expires
    )
    return {"access_token": access_token, "token_type": "bearer", "valid_till": f"{expires} UTC"}


@app.get("/protected_route")
async def protected_route(user: dict = Depends(get_current_user)):
    print("DEBUG: [/protected_route()]:", user)
    return {"message": "This route is protected, and you are authenticated successfully"}
```

It is able to generate and use JWT, however, even if I try with wrong AD credentials through Postman, it is still working.

In addition, is there a way I can check AD Group membership before issuing JWT?

Comment: When you say AD, you mean classic, on-premise Active Directory, not Azure Active Directory, right? Classic AD doesn't natively support JWT for ticket exchange, you'll need to build some external session handling service that uses JWT's as proxies for the underlying identity. Azure AD on the other hand supports JWTs out of the box :)

Comment: You are correct, I am using on-prem AD. I will check in that direction.